# iOS: stop indefinite number of request

Tags: ios, request, nsoperation, nsoperationqueue, alamofire

In my class I have this code:

This is the method that download a JSON and check if inside each element is there a url to download a file and I can stop "my_doc_r" when I want

```
func requestDocuments(completion:(response:AnyObject)->()){

         my_doc_r = request(.POST, "http://example.com/json/docs")
            .responseJSON { (_, _, JSON, error) in

                if error == nil{

                    var array = JSON as! NSArray
                    completion(response:array)

                    self.attachments_to_download = 0

                    for var i = 0; i < array.count; ++i{

                        if array.objectAtIndex(i).objectForKey("file_url") as! String != ""{

                            var url_file = array.objectAtIndex(i).objectForKey("file_url") as! String

                            self.downLoadFile(url_file)
                        }
                    }                  
                }
                else{

                }

        }


    }
```

Otherwise here I have a indefinite number of "download" request, and if I need to stop all? what can I do?
I tried with the manager but I didn't obtain good results.
What can I do if I want stop all download?
Or the best solution is to attend that one download is finished to start another?

```
func downLoadFile(url:String){

        download(.GET, url, { (temporaryURL, response) in
            if let directoryURL = NSFileManager.defaultManager()
                .URLsForDirectory(.DocumentDirectory,
                    inDomains: .UserDomainMask)[0]
                as? NSURL {

                    let pathComponent = response.suggestedFilename

                    var finalPath = NSURL()

                    finalPath = directoryURL.URLByAppendingPathComponent(pathComponent!)

                    //check same file with same name, delete and replace
                    if NSFileManager.defaultManager().fileExistsAtPath(finalPath.absoluteString!) {
                        NSFileManager.defaultManager().removeItemAtPath(finalPath.absoluteString!, error: nil)
                    }

                    return finalPath
            }

            return temporaryURL
        })


    }
```

Comment: I would love to help but I don't understand your question. Could you possibly take another pass and attempt to clarify what it is that you're trying to figure out? Are you trying to figure out how to cancel a running request?

Comment: yes... you can see in my code that I do the "download" request in method "downloadFile" without specifying a declared request for download... but if I want stop all download?

Answer (score 0):

Finally I found a solution:

I changed the first line and add at end one line inside my:

```
func downLoadFile(url:String){

let my_req_down = download(.GET, url, { (temporaryURL, response) in //define the request

......
......

downloads_requests.addObject(my_req_down) //add all request in an array
}
```

and when I want cancel all request:

```
for var i = 0; i < downloads_requests.count; i++ {

            var r :AnyObject!
            r = downloads_requests.objectAtIndex(i) as! Request

            if r != nil{

                (r as! Request).cancel()
            }
        }
```

and it work very fine!!!